# How to sync two values via data-target and data-value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one `span` with description which is being changed when an `object` is being clicked. I also have another `span` which has to sync in real time with first `span`, to show the same information. Using one id for two spans doesn't work.

```js
//changes data of description
const tasks = ['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4', 'Task 5', 'Task 6', 'Task 7'];
$('[data-target]').on("click", "li", function() {
  const clicked = $(this).addClass("active");
  clicked.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(clicked.parent().data('target')).text(tasks[clicked.index()]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="amodal">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;">
      //span we need to sync with first span
      <span id="adescr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="list-group" id="a" data-target="#descr">
  <li class="list-group-item" id="a1">
    <span>Задание 1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;">
    //first span
    <span id="descr" data-bind="aadescr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please try to tidy up the HTML

Comment: @JaromandaX Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using same id for two spans doesn't work

Correct, but a unique class name used for both *will* work.

```
data-target=".descr"
```

```js
//changes data of description
const tasks = ['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4', 'Task 5', 'Task 6', 'Task 7'];
$('[data-target]').on("click", "li", function() {
  const clicked = $(this).addClass("active");
  clicked.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(clicked.parent().data('target')).text(tasks[clicked.index()]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="amodal">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 76px;">
      <!--span we need to sync with first span-->
      <span class="descr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="list-group" id="a" data-target=".descr">
  <li class="list-group-item" id="a1">
    <span>Задание 1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;">
    <!--first span-->
    <span class="descr" data-bind="aadescr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Now, when you click on the`[data-target]>li` it will update both the "first span" and the "span we need to sync".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very crude plugin function `$.fn.bindText()` you could call instead of `text()` and it will use the `data-bind` attribute to update the associated element also

```js
const tasks = ['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4', 'Task 5', 'Task 6', 'Task 7'];

$.fn.bindText = function(txt) {
  $('#' + $(this).data('bind')).add(this).text(txt);
}

$('[data-target]').on("click", "li", function() {
  const clicked = $(this).addClass("active");
  clicked.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(clicked.parent().data('target')).bindText(tasks[clicked.index()]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="amodal">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;">
      //span we need to sync with first span
      <span id="adescr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="list-group" id="a" data-target="#descr">
  <li class="list-group-item" id="a1">
    <span>Задание 1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;">
    //first span
    <span id="descr" data-bind="adescr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
</ul>
```